# Asp.net Core 2.0 identity with cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-core

I referred to article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/compatibility/cookie-sharing and I want to make sure two of my asp.net core apps can login at the same time. I am using asp.net identity and same database for identity. 
By following the instructions on article, I added this in Startup.cs of both web applications.
In ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddCookie("ApplicationCookie",options =>
            {
                var protectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\shared-auth-ticket-keys\"));
                options.DataProtectionProvider = protectionProvider;
                options.TicketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(protectionProvider.CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", "Cookies", "v2"));
            });
```

and this line in Configure method:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

But when I log in one application, it doesn't login other application. If I login from other application, it logouts from first application. Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong here and how I can fix it?
Other than this change, I added this line in Login (get) action

```
if (_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
```

Other than this, all other code is same as default template with individual user accounts for both applications.

Comment: Cookies are not stored between applications. In order to do this, you will have to use something like IdentityServer4: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/

Comment: More specifically cookies are not shared across domains. Are both of your apps under the same domain?
Are the apps using different versions of ASP.NET Core? There's a known issue with DataProtection that can break across versions.

Comment: For now, both apps are on different local host ports. Both are using asp.net core 2.0. They both are in same solution.